# Get values inside quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Get values inside quotes in javascript, like in discord dyno bot uses `?poll "<title>" "<choice>" "<choice>"`, How do split the array so that I get the values of the title and choices in javascript

Comment: There is no array. This is string`?poll "<title>" "<choice>" "<choice>"` .Please add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: as I told I need to split this string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using regex

```
/(?<=")[^"]+/
```

```js
const str = `?poll "<title>" "<choice>" "<choice>"`;
const result = str.match(/(?<=")[^"]+/g).filter((s) => s.trim());
console.log(result);
```

**2)** If lookbehind is not supported then you can do as:

```
/"[^"]+/
```

```js
const str = `?poll "<title>" "<choice>" "<choice>"`;
const result = str
  .match(/"[^"]+/g)
  .map((s) => s.slice(1))
  .filter((s) => s.trim());
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It works, marking as solution